# Pandas single column apply function error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I use below statement, it prints all of the series and then throws an error
`dff_g.apply(func=print(dff_g['relationship_status']))`

The error is

`TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index marriageId'`

`marriageId` is the first column of the dataframe

My bigger goal is to pass multiple columns to a function using `apply` method. But this is a basic error I am getting

Comment: You are passing `None` as your `func` argument, since `print` always returns `None`. Perhaps you mean to pass a *function* to `func` that prints something? Although, probably that isn't a good use of `dff_g.apply`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have tried other functions too. It gives me similar errors. `TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index marriageId')`. As for print, it prints all the rows and then throws the error. My questions is: Why it doesn't stop once the function is applied on all the rows

Comment: **You never apply a function**. You **aren't passing a function** to `func`, you are passing the value `None`, which is why you are throwing an error, because `None` isn't *callable*.

Comment: In other words, you need to *pass a function*, instead, you *call a function*, then pass the value that is returned: `func=print(dff_g['relationship_status'])` So the function get's called, it prints `dff_g['relationship_status']`, then `print` returns `None`, which you pass to the argument `func`, which throws the error you are seeng.

Comment: any hope of considering my answer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
dff_g['relationship_status'].apply(print)
```

that would apply print() on the selected column, without parethesis so the actual function is passed instead of the value returned by the function call